# pandas not modifying df

Tags: python, pandas

new to pandas here. I have a df:

```
inked=tracker[['A','B','C','D','AA','BB','CC', 'DD', 'E', 'F']]
```

single letter column names contain names and double letter column names contain numbers but also NaN.

I am converting all NaN to zeros by using this:

```
inked.loc[:,'AA':'DD'].fillna(0)
```

and it works, but when I  do

```
inked.head()
```

I get the original df with the NaN. How can I make the change permanently in the df?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `fillna()` is not performed in place.  If you were operating directly on the DataFrame, then you could use the `inplace=True` argument, like this:

```
inked.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

However, if you first select a subset of the columns, using `loc`, then the results are lost.

This was covered [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11984).  Basically, you need to re-assign the updated DataFrame back to the original DataFrame.  For a list of columns (rather than a range, like you originally tried), you can do this:

```
inked[['AA','DD']] = inked[['AA','DD']].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general when performing dataframe operations, when you want to alter a dataframe you either need to re-assign it to itself, or to a new variable. (In my experience at least)
`inked = inked.loc[:,'AA':'DD'].fillna(0)`

Comment: I deleted mine because the `.loc[]` operation creates a separate copy, so even if we make `fillna()` work in place, it is operating on temporary data.

Comment: Similarly, I think your solution has the problem that it will remove the columns that are not between `'AA'` and `'DD'`.

Comment: so, I shouldn't use loc? what would be the alternative? you are right, I applied your answer right away and it still didn't work

Comment: `inked = inked.loc[:,'AA':'DD'].fillna(0)` didn't work either. I get an error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) make it sound like `loc` is supposed to work, but my local experiments with IPython (using Python 2.7) are not working.  At least not when I slice out a subset of the columns, as you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: tracker is actually an Excel file. could I convert the NaN when I do the `pd.read_excel` for only those columns?

Comment: Try `inked.loc[:,'AA':'DD'] = inked.loc[:,'AA':'DD'].fillna(0)`

Comment: @ALollz , that gives me this error:` AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'` do you know what that means?

Comment: @user7146708 Not sure. My guess is that a lot of these operations ruined whatever you were doing and now `inked` is no longer a `DataFrame`. Just re-initialize inked and try that.